# Unable to build job on jenkins for node application

Tags: node.js, shell, jenkins, npm

I am using node version 4.4.5 and npm version is 5.3.0.
jenkins version is 2.46.2.

At the time of build I am getting this exception:

`/bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson7756731843340614304.sh
+ PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
+ npm install
/tmp/hudson7756731843340614304.sh: 6: /tmp/hudson7756731843340614304.sh: npm: not found`

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

```
The execute shell consist of:
#echo "PATH is :$PATH"
#echo "node version is :'node -v' "
#echo "npm version is:'npm -v' "
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
npm install
npm run coverage
zip -r EngagementSystemNodeApi.zip .
```

What need to be done plz suggest.

Comment: Do you use the NodeJS Plugin?

Comment: yes i have installed this plugin

Comment: Let me be more precise: Do you intend use a node / npm installation provided by that plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't run `npm` from the commandline.  Install and use [Jenkins NodeJS plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin).  It allows you to configure multiple versions of node and it puts them on the `PATH`

Comment: I have added the plugin still I am getting this error

Comment: It's not sufficient to add the plugin without configuring the job to use it. You have to remove your 'execute shell' build step to 'execute nodejs script' build step.  The plugin docs in the above link are good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

have you set the enviroment variable in the jenkins machine?

Comment: Sorry, you weren't using windows cmd. Try installing apt-get install nodejs-legacy. After installation check, in the Jenkins machine bash, if node --version command works